# Navigation Items Overflow

Tags: ios

I have a navigation bar that has many items, that may not all fit depending on the device size. How can I calculate how many of the UIBarButtonItems fit in the navigation bar? Doing barButtonItem.width is giving me zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not supported by Apple, so I ended up using Size Classes + Orientation to determine the number of buttons to show.